# Transform perspective CSS only to container, not content

Tags: css, transform, perspective

When I try to use "perspective" property and then "transform: rotateY(10deg)" the effect applies to the children elements too. I want a rectangle with perspective but don't want the text inside to be in perspective. Any idea?

I've created a JSFIDDLE example
https://jsfiddle.net/j0ofgbLo/1/

```css
.container {
    perspective: 500px;
}

.content{
   transform: rotateY(-45deg);
   background: #ddd;
    min-width: 100px;    
    padding: 0 20px;    
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h3>Text</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you provide some code to work on?

Comment: provide some sample code or create a fiddle of it

Comment: I made a fiddle example

Answer (score 5):

The CSS perspective-property just applies perspective to the children not itself. To get an "unflattened"/perspective result, just put this rule on your content-element:

```
transform-style: preserve-3d;
```

And put this on your H3-element:

```
transform: rotateY(45deg);
```

If the content-element is transformed or has perspective it builds a containing-block and a stacking-context, so the chidren are forced to render to this layer anyway. That means you cannot use fixed elements in an transformed context (in IE11+ you can) to skip the ancestors transformations. So you have to reverse the transformations on the target element (H3) in perspective to get an undistorted result.

```css
.container 
{
    perspective: 500px;
}

.content
{
   transform: rotateY(-45deg);
   background: #ddd;
   min-width: 100px;    
   padding: 0 20px;    
   transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

h3
{
   transform: rotateY(45deg); 
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="content">
        <h3>Text</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add a jsfiddle or a example please?

Comment: I have added a code snippet. Without vendor prefixes, so run it in a current browser.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I solved this. Here is the codepen and the code if someone want to make something similar:

http://codepen.io/marinagallardo/pen/jPjBMV

```css
.heading {
  background: red;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: white;
  position: relative;
  height: 40px;
  transform: skewX(-1deg);
}
.heading p {
  padding: 0 20px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 100;
  margin-top: 10px;
  transform: skewX(1deg);
}
.heading:before {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  top: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  transform: skewY(-2deg);
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
.heading:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  height: 50%;
  background: red;
  transform: skewY(2deg);
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -10px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="heading">
  <p>Texto</p>
</div>


<div class="heading">
  <p>Texto a top de largo</p>
</div>



<div class="heading">
  <p>Prácticamente escribiendo el quijote</p>
</div>


<div class="heading">
  <p>Prácticamente escribiendo el quijote, lo cual es una prueba</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to put out the container and wrap container and content with a div. I create a fiddle working, the first block is like you defined (container and content inherit perspective), and the second block is like I tell you with a wrapper (perspective only for container, not for content).

http://jsfiddle.net/c72b5184/1/

The code is like this (note that the correct version is `.wrapper *`)

```
.container {
    background-color: blue;
    width: 200px;
    transform: rotateY(50deg);
    height: 200px;
}
.content {
    background-color: green;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin: 20px 0;
}
.wrapper .container,
.wrapper .content{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="container"></div>
    <div class="content"></div>
</div>
```